# Find a string in a string which starts and ends with different string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have complete html of a page and from that I need to find GA (google Analytics) id of it. For example:

```
<script>ga('create', 'UA-4444444444-1', 'auto');</script>
```

From above string I need to get UA-4444444444-1, which starts from "UA-" and ends with "-1".  I have tried this:

```
re.findall(r"\"trackingId\"\s?:\s?\"(UA-\d+-\d+)\"", raw_html)
```

but didn't get any success. Please let me know what mistake I am making.

Thanks

Comment: The input string you give doesn't have trackingId anywhere in it and the UA- stuff isn't surrounded by quotes but apostrophes...

Comment: `re.findall(r"UA-\d+-\d+")` seems like enough...

Comment: @ulysse Thank you :) re.findall(r"UA-\d+-\d+") worked..

Comment: Made it an answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are overthinking it, you could just seek for the UA token directly:

```
re.findall(r"UA-\d+-\d+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use regex in parsing through the html. BeautifulSoup should be find in extracting text from tags. Here we extract script tags from html, then we apply regex to text located in script tags.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4


html = "<script>ga('create', 'UA-4444444444-1', 'auto');</script>"

soup = bs4(html, 'lxml')

pattern = re.compile("UA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+")
ids = []
for i in soup.findAll("script"):
    ids.append(pattern.findall(i.text)[0])
print(ids)
```